# Multi language ASP.NET website (with friendly URLs) without using MVC

Tags: asp.net, url, multilingual

I am developing a website with multiple languages (Two) and it must have friendly URLs for optimize SEO. I'm using normal globalization (CurrentCulture + resource files in both languages). Now I have a Global.asax file with the following code:

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SampleWeb" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<script runat="server">

Private Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.asxd/{*pathInfo}")
    'Route Path
    'Default Route Values
    'constraint to say the locale must be 2 letters. You could also use 
something like "en-us|en-gn|ru" to specify a full list of languages
    'Instance of a class to handle the routing
    routes.Add(New Route("{locale}/{*url}", Nothing, New 
RouteValueDictionary() From { _
        {"locale", "[a-z]{2}"} _
    }, New Utility.Handlers.DefaultRouteHandeler()))

End Sub


Private Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

End Sub


</script>
```

And a file called `DefaultRouteHandeler.vb` inside the `App_Code` folder, it contains the following code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Compilation
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports System.Web.UI

Namespace Utility.Handlers
Public Class DefaultRouteHandeler
    Implements IRouteHandler
    Public Function GetHttpHandler(requestContext As RequestContext) As 
IHttpHandler
        'Url mapping however you want here: 

        Dim routeURL As String =    
TryCast(requestContext.RouteData.Values("url"), String)

        Dim pageUrl As String = "~/" + (If(Not    
[String].IsNullOrEmpty(routeURL), routeURL, ""))

        Dim page = 
TryCast(BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(pageUrl, 
GetType(Page)), IHttpHandler)
        If page IsNot Nothing Then
            'Set the <form>'s postback url to the route 
            Dim webForm = TryCast(page, Page)
            If webForm IsNot Nothing Then
                webForm.Load += Sub() webForm.Form.Action = 
requestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
            End If
        End If
        Return page
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

When I run the site the following error message appears:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Compile error Description: An error
>   occurred during the compilation of a resource      required to service
>   this request. Please review the following specific  error details and
>   modify your source code accordingly.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30149: Class 'DefaultRouteHandeler' must 
>   implement 'Function GetHttpHandler (RequestContext As RequestContext)
>   As  IHttpHandler' for 'System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler' interface.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Línea 9:  Namespace Utility.Handlers Línea 10:     Public Class
>   DefaultRouteHandeler Línea 11:         Implements IRouteHandler Línea
>   12:         Public Function GetHttpHandler(requestContext As
>   RequestContext) As IHttpHandler Línea 13:             'Url mapping
>   however you want here:
>
> Source File: C:\Mysite\App_Code\DefaultRouteHandeler.vb Line 11

Why it is showing this error?

I got those codes from this question: [Add second language support with root path in an existing ASP.NET WebForms site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072088/add-second-language-support-with-root-path-in-an-existing-asp-net-webforms-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the Implements clause after the function.

```
Public Function GetHttpHandler(requestContext As RequestContext) As 
IHttpHandler Implements IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler
```

UPDATE:  Give this a try

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Compilation
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports System.Web.UI

Namespace SampleWeb.Utility.Handlers
    Public Class DefaultRouteHandler
        Implements IRouteHandler

        Public Function GetHttpHandler(requestContext As RequestContext) As IHttpHandler Implements IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler
            'Url mapping however you want here: 

            Dim routeURL As String = TryCast(requestContext.RouteData.Values("url"), String)

            Dim pageUrl As String = "~/" + (If(Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(routeURL), routeURL, ""))

            Dim page = TryCast(BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(pageUrl, GetType(Page)), IHttpHandler)
            If page IsNot Nothing Then
                'Set the <form>'s postback url to the route 
                Dim webForm As Page = TryCast(page, Page)
                If webForm IsNot Nothing Then
                    AddHandler webForm.Load, AddressOf webForm_Load
                End If
            End If
            Return page
        End Function

        Protected Sub webForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        End Sub
    End Class


End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help, i did what you recommend, but now, i'm getting this error message: Compiler Error Message: BC32022: 'Public Event Load (sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event and can not be called directly. Use the RaiseEvent statement to generate an event.

Source Error:


Line 21: Dim webform = TryCast (Page, Page)
Line 22: If webform IsNot Nothing Then
Line 23: webForm.Load + = Sub () webForm.Form.Action = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
Line 24: End If
Line 25: End If


Source File: C:\mysite\App_Code\DefaultRouteHandeler.vb Line: 23

Comment: Q:  Was this code originally C# code that was converted to VB.NET?

Comment: "Use RaiseEvent statement to generate an event"  In VB.NET you use the RaiseEvent in the declaration.  It's been a few years since I worked with web forms but I am going back to some old code now for reference for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be waiting for your help. Yes, it was originally C# code, but i converted that code with this: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Yes.  I see.  That is the issue.  C# deals with events differently and the code needs modification after translation.   I am working on something for you now.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, i posted another question in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679999/add-friendly-urls-to-multi-lingual-asp-net-website-without-using-mvc